# How to mock forEach behavior with Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I want to make the following work, but I don't know how to mock forEach behavior properly. (The code is taken from a related question [Testing Java enhanced for behavior with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379308/testing-java-enhanced-for-behavior-with-mockito) )

```
@Test
public void aa() {
  Collection<String> fruits;
  Iterator<String> fruitIterator;

  fruitIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
  when(fruitIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, true, true, false);
  when(fruitIterator.next()).thenReturn("Apple")
      .thenReturn("Banana").thenReturn("Pear");

  fruits = mock(Collection.class);
  when(fruits.iterator()).thenReturn(fruitIterator);
  doCallRealMethod().when(fruits).forEach(any(Consumer.class));

  // this doesn't work (it doesn't print anything)
  fruits.forEach(f -> {
    mockObject.someMethod(f); 
  });

  // this works fine
  /*
  int iterations = 0;
  for (String fruit : fruits) {
    mockObject.someMethod(f); 
  }
  */

  // I want to verify something like this
  verify(mockObject, times(3)).someMethod(anyString());
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I think your question gets answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379308/testing-java-enhanced-for-behavior-with-mockito

Comment: mocking iterator() is fine. I think mocking iterator() and mocking forEach() is different thing since forEach() doesn't call iterator().

Comment: I changed the example code to make it more clear.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? I expect that you ultimately want to confirm that something happens to each element of the fruits collection. In this example, it's just printing to the console but your actual application may be more complex. Is that right? I can post an answer with suggestions with just a little more information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I edited the question to make it more clear. I basically want to verify that some method is called properly in the forEach loop.

Answer (score 12):

```
Iterator mockIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
doCallRealMethod().when(fruits).forEach(any(Consumer.class));
when(fruits.iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockObject);
```

Answer (score 9):

The method `forEach` of the `Collection` interface is a "defender" method; it does not use `Iterator` but call the `Consumer` passed to the method.

If you are using Mockito version 2+ (*), you can ask the default method `forEach` of the `Collection` interface to be called:

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(fruits).forEach(Mockito.any(Consumer.class));
```

Note that the "defender" method is actually going to request an `Iterator` to traverse the collection, hence will use the `Iterator` you mocked in your test. It wouldn't work if no `Iterator` was provided by the mocked collection, as with `when(fruits.iterator()).thenReturn(fruitIterator)`

(*): Mockito has added the possibility to support Java 8 default ("defender") method since version 2 - you can check the tracking issue [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/186).

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I tried with "doCallRealMethod" but, it doesn't work. I edited the sample code to have doCallRealMethod. Is this what you are saying ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: It seems my intellij issue. I can make it work with your suggestion from command-line. thank you.

Comment: Any Kotlin version?