# How to mock Kotlin's List.forEach?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, powermock, robolectric, mockito-kotlin

For the given code below, in Kotlin, it's not possible to execute the function `forEach` (or anything similar, `map`, `filter`, so on...) because `BarList`  is mocked. So the native implementation of `forEach` and relatives are not being called. After a bit of search on the internet I came with this:

```kotlin
public class BarList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements OrderedBarCollection<E> { 
    //...
}
//...

val mockedList: BarList<Foo> = mockBarList()
val fooList = listOf(Foo())

`when`(mockedList.iterator()).thenReturn(fooList.iterator())
`when`(mockedList.size).thenReturn(fooList.size)

com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin
    .doCallRealMethod()
    .`when`(mockedList)
    .forEach(Mockito.any<Consumer<Foo>>()) //Attempt to call the Consumer.

mockedList.forEach { foo ->
    //Not executing
}
```

*I tried this above based on the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407513/2430555*

I also tried:

```kotlin
com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.doCallRealMethod().`when`(mockedList).forEach(any())
```

But it's causing:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
//...
```

The definition of `forEach` in the Kotlin source code is:

```kotlin
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit
```

I think I should replace `any()` with something that matches `action: (T) -> Unit`, but I am not sure how to do this.
I don't mind to use interactor if needed, but I need to at least make `forEach` run as expected. Could you guys please help me?

Regards,

Pedro

Comment: Why are you mocking the list? Can you not create an instance of the list with whatever fake data you want to test with?

Comment: Reason: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleRealmTest.java#L48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn` for the mocked list.

```kotlin
`when`(mockedList.iterator()).thenAnswer { fooList.iterator() }
```

Reason:

Author: Tobias Berger

> an iterator is only good for going through the list once. Therefore
> you usually get a new one every time you call the iterator() function.
> If you mock that with thenReturn(messageList.iterator()) , it will
> just call that once on messageList and reuse that iterator instance
> every time you try to get one for your mock. Once your first loop over
> this iterator is finished, it will always say it has no more items.
> With thenAnswer you define a supplier that is called each time your
> mocked function is used, providing a new iterator for each call (as
> would be expected)

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot mock extension funcitons at all, while they are not members of target class.

`forEach` is Just outer helper for `Iterable`

In this case you will be still calling usual `forEach` of kotlin on `fooList`.

And i don't understand what is the motivation to mock collections especially substitute iterator of mocking `OrderedBarCollection` with simple `ArrayList` (`listOf`), what is requirement to do it?

Comment: Please read this: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7000